# How to uniquely convert an integer to a random unique alphanumeric string?

Tags: c#

I have a table which users create their account in when they sign up to my application.

When the user account is created, I want it to also create an 8 character alpanumeric string that uniquely represents their account, sort of like integer obfuscation. I want to be able to support up to 2 billion user accounts so the algorithm needs to be able to support unique hash mapping of the id to alphanumeric key for this many numbers with no colisions.

My language of choice is C#.

The reason for this is that I want customers to be able to share their code (much like a phone number) to other customers who can then search for them based on this code and add them as friends. I don't want to reveal user id's for obvious security reasons so a customer should be able to view their code on their screen, give it to their friends and their friends can find them based on the code.

Does anyone have any suggestions how this could be achieved?

Comment: Why can't you simply hash it?

Comment: I assume it needs to be reversible?  How secure does it need to be?

Comment: This is a poor question for stack overflow and should be on [programmers.stackexchange.com - Programmers Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development.](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: You can just use a counter for id generation `{1, 2, 3, ...}` and translate it to an alphanumeric string by changing the base of the number and using each digit as a different character.

Comment: create a random 8 charactor number, create a guid on the table as unique user id when  the user is created. Make a pointer table between the guid and number, each time a new user is created generate a random number, check the table to make sure it doesn't exist.

Comment: You want a [multiplicative inverse](http://ericlippert.com/2013/11/14/a-practical-use-of-multiplicative-inverses/). It's easy to implement and quite effective.

Comment: It doesn't need to be secure, I just want customers to be able to exchange a unique reference to their account that doesn't then let you easily work out the user-id